# Showing KPI on windows 8 app

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I want to show the KPI from SQL server analysis service to a windows app.

I don't have experience with SSAS. Basically I am asking how can I show BI KPI in any external application

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about SSAS KPIs but it seems that there are (at least) two options:

- KPIs are [exposed directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.kpi%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) through the ADOMD.NET provider
- They can be [queried using MDX](http://www.infotoad.com/blog/post/2012/12/16/Creating-a-simple-Key-Performance-Indicator-%28KPI%29-using-SQL-Server-Analysis-Services-%28SSAS%29-2012.aspx)

So you just need to write an application that can issue MDX queries and/or use the ADOMD.NET provider.